# Mix in some SQL in a HQL query

Tags: sql, oracle, nhibernate, hql

I'm reading metadata from the database and building queries based on that.

For performance reasons, our DBA has created a function to select a certain piece of data. It looks like this:

```
SELECT tab.id, packName.fnName(p1 => tab.id, p2 => 5), packName.fnName(p1 => tab.id, p2 => 7)
FROM table tab
```

(Table is mapped in NHibernate)

Is it possible to add this sort of select to a HQL query? I'm using a `Transformers.AliasToBean` so where the result of the fnName() goes is not a problem.

Comment: It's possible--but is the `=>` syntax specific to Oracle? What's going on there?

Comment: `p1 => tab.id` are named parameters. I'm pretty sure it is optional. And it's not a problem if the solution will work on Oracle only, they will never move to another database (or a whole lot of other code needs to be rewritten first)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to accomplish this by creating a custom dialect and registering your function with that dialect:

```csharp
public class MyCustomDialect : Oracle10gDialect // or whatever version you're using
{
    public MyCustomDialect()
    {
        RegisterFunction(
            "packname",
            new SQLFunctionTemplate(
                NHibernateUtil.String, "packName.fnName(p1 => ?1, p2 => ?2)"));
    }
}
```

You then have to configure NHibernate to use your custom dialect (you're already doing this somewhere, etiher via XML in your hibernate.cfg.xml file, or in configuration code). Just replace the current dialect with this custom one.

Now you should be able to just call your function in HQL:

```csharp
session.CreateQuery(
        "select tab.id, packname(tab.id, 5), packname(tab.id, 7) from table tab")
    .TransformUsing(....);
```

Which should generate SQL that looks like this:

```
select
    tab.id
    packName.fnName(p1 => tab0_.id, p2 => 5) as col_0_0_,
    packName.fnName(p1 => tab0_.id, p2 => 7) as col_0_1_
from
    Table tab0_
```

Note that if you want to use this function with Criteria, QueryOver, or LINQ-to-NHibernate you can, and there aren't too many more steps needed to make this happen.

Answer (score 1):

seems like you can use formula to achieve this,

```
<property name="FnName1" formula="(SELECT packName.fnName(p1 => tab.id, p2 => 5) FROM table tab)"/>
<property name="FnName2" formula="(SELECT packName.fnName(p1 => tab.id, p2 => 7) FROM table tab)"/>
```

Ref : http://ayende.com/blog/3936/nhibernate-mapping-property

Comment: I'd like to select this `FnName` only when necessary, in most cases it is not necessary to do the extra subselects. Do I need a specific NHibernate mapping for this? Or is there another solution?

Comment: What I'm afraid of here: Needing an extra `Entity` and mapping file for this specific case...

Comment: You could map it to your existing entity where value is actually required and set it as lazy, then it will only execute when you actually access the value.